# Redirect users according to http_referrer

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, referrer

I recently updated my website. My problem is that:

There are few hyperlinks of my previous site in pdfs and word files  located in webpages.
Moreover there are few hyperlinks of my previous site in few webpages.

What I want, is to redirect the traffic coming from those files and urls to a new url.

I tried modifying .htaccess as following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://www.referrer-url.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.pdf http://my-new-url.com/ [L,R]
</IfModule>
```

But nothing appears

Comment: I doubt that clicking on a link in a PDF or Word document, will get you a referrer pointing to any website.

Comment: isn't it possible to get the server in which the pdf is stored to?

Comment: How exactly are users viewing those files?

Comment: they are browsing to a webpage. i.e. they view online: http://www.othersite.com/text.pdf which has a hyperlink that I would like to redirect.

Comment: At least in case of Word documents, that is still going to need some kind of plugin, I suppose, I don’t think any browser can display those natively. And in that case, this would probably need the plugin to pass that information on the the browser, when opening a link from within the document … which I doubt will actually happen. But you should be able to test that yourself, using your browser dev tools - check what request headers get send.

Comment: What I wonder is: why do you need to consult the referrer at all? If you migrated then I would expect that the old URL won't work any longer. So why won't you redirect _all_ requests to those resources?

Comment: Because I use the old url with my new website.